# Using JFrame with Netbeans on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans

I want to run this code that will create a window with a simple button on it. The program will run in Netbeans on a Mac but the problem is that it does not work. Here is the code below.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Test {

    public static JButton button(){
    JButton button = new JButton("random button");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    button();
    new JFrame();

    }
    }
```

Please help me figure this out soon please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're not adding the button to anything or displaying the JFrame. Your method returns a JButton object, but you're not doing anything with this object.

- Create a JPanel
- Add the JButton to the JPanel
- Add the JPanel to the JFrame
- Display the JFrame by calling `setVisible(true)`
- Most important:  Making up code and hoping it will magically work is not a successful heuristic for learning to program. Instead read the Swing tutorials which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

---

For example

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(button);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("foo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}
```